# Reusing the same string before inserting to a list seems to pass by value?

Tags: c++, stl

```
list<string> l;
string s;

getline(cin, s);
l.push_back(s);
getline(cin, s);
l.push_back(s);
```

Using input

```
123
test
```

Printing the list 'l' results:

```
123
test
```

Shouldn't this print:

```
test
test
```

I'm a little confused as to why the string is being passed by value.

Comment: Right.  Why were you expecting otherwise?

Comment: I think Christopher is confusing Java List and C++ list

Comment: @user440336: amazing how someone can come to expect something so broken :-).  C++'s behaviour is far more intuitive, the Java/C#/Ruby behaviour a way to try to make code written without any thought to ownership perform ok (as that's generally intangible), assuming people will learn to clone stuff when the results are wrong (as that's more likely to be noticed).  But only for objects, right, as it'd be too obviously weird if strings and numbers behaved like that too 8->...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push_back` *copies* the string object `s` passed into it. So wahetever modification you do to `s` is not affecting the pushed back value.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't, because the string is copied when you add it to the list `l`. `string` argument **is** passed by reference to [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/):

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str );
```

Comment: But according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_back/ (void push_back ( const T& x );) the argument appears to be passed by reference.

Comment: @Christopher Dorian: The argument may be passed by reference, but that doesn't prevent the `push_back` from making a copy of the passed object and storing it in its internal datastrucures.

Comment: @Chris: That's not enough for you to deduce what it does *with* that reference. You need to read the docs more carefully.

Comment: @Christopher: In your link, it even says, under **Parameters:**, "x Value to be *copied* to the new element."

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading; you don't have a loop anywhere in the code that you posted.

The string is being passed by value to `push_back`, which makes a copy in the `list`. The results you're getting are exactly what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
void list::push_back(string& s)
{
   list_.add(new string(s));   // copy string
}
```

You see, the string is copied in push_back method. It is passed by reference just to avoid a redundant copying.

```
void list::push_back(string s) // copy string
{
   list_.add(new string(s));   // copy string
}
```

Comment: Good points, but your pseudocode should accept `s` by *const* string reference.